# Javascript to prompt for pdf files to insert?

Tags: javascript, pdf, button, form-fields

I am attempting to have a button on a form that will launch file explorer for the user to select pdf files to insert into form.

The *insertPages* script will insert pages from a specific *cPath*, but I need the user to be able to select the pages to insert, as they will be different from case to case. Is there a way to accomplish this using javascript?

I am using Bluebeam, which is very similar to Acrobat. I have created several templates and javascript code using the Acrobat API Reference, and thus far the Bluebeam engine appears to operate nearly identically. In a perfect world, the button would launch the "Insert Pages" menu in Bluebeam.

Thanks in advance for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

If this were Acrobat, I'd use app.browseForDoc(). The returned object has three properties...

cFS - A string containing the resulting file system name for the chosen file.

cPath - A string containing the resulting path for the chosen file.

cURL - A string containing the resulting URL for the chosen file.

Get the full path to the file from there then use insertPages.

In Acrobat, it can only be run in a Privileged context. I'm not sure if it will work the same way in BlueBeam though they have done a fairly good job of duplicating the form field related JavaScripts.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. unfortunately _browseForDoc_ is not available in the BlueBeam API. Although, it seems like there may be another way to get the path. I do have a _browseForFileToSubmit_ script, which can be used to the path of a specified file, and then I can dimension the path and insert the file. This would be sufficient, but I need to go a step further and be able to select multiple files.

Is there any means of launching File Explorer and selecting multiple files at once?

Thank you again for your help. The unfamiliar API is tough to work with and get answers for.

Comment: Because Acrobat can't select multiple files, I doubt the BlueBeam API would allow for that either. However, if there are a limited number of pages that need to be inserted, just in different combinations, you may be able to use template pages. In Acrobat, Template pages are hidden until they are shown via a script. I can't find a JavaScript reference for BlueBeam so I can't tell you if that's an option for you... but it is in Acrobat.